# KVM Virtual guest Paused on Reboot

Tags: linux, redhat, kvm-virtualization

I'm running REHL 6 and just installed a Ubuntu Server Guest via KVM set to start at boot. This works correctly and the guest loads, but it loads "paused" and requires that I manually un-pause it. Can someone give me a hint as to how I can I get the Guest OS to actually become active on boot?

Here is the libvert dump as requested...Also tried libvert auto-start --- no effect.

```
<domain type='kvm' id='1'>
  <name>MailServer</name>
  <uuid>a61dae75-1f5c-d536-718f-3c615d9b4868</uuid>
  <memory>4194304</memory>
  <currentMemory>4194304</currentMemory>
  <vcpu>4</vcpu>
  <os>
    <type arch='x86_64' machine='rhel6.0.0'>hvm</type>
    <boot dev='hd'/>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/>
    <apic/>
    <pae/>
  </features>
  <clock offset='utc'/>
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
  <on_crash>restart</on_crash>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/libexec/qemu-kvm</emulator>
    <disk type='file' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw' cache='none'/>
      <source file='/home/MailServer/MailServer-1.img'/>
      <target dev='hda' bus='ide'/>
      <alias name='ide0-0-0'/>
      <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='0' unit='0'/>
    </disk>
    <disk type='block' device='cdrom'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
      <target dev='hdc' bus='ide'/>
      <readonly/>
      <alias name='ide0-1-0'/>
      <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='1' unit='0'/>
    </disk>
    <controller type='ide' index='0'>
      <alias name='ide0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x01' function='0x1'/>
    </controller>
    <interface type='bridge'>
      <mac address='52:54:00:cd:f9:9f'/>
      <source bridge='br0'/>
      <target dev='vnet0'/>
      <model type='virtio'/>
      <alias name='net0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
    <serial type='pty'>
      <source path='/dev/pts/1'/>
      <target port='0'/>
      <alias name='serial0'/>
    </serial>
    <console type='pty' tty='/dev/pts/1'>
      <source path='/dev/pts/1'/>
      <target port='0'/>
      <alias name='serial0'/>
    </console>
    <input type='mouse' bus='ps2'/>
    <graphics type='vnc' port='5900' autoport='yes'/>
    <sound model='ac97'>
      <alias name='sound0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x04' function='0x0'/>
    </sound>
    <video>
      <model type='cirrus' vram='9216' heads='1'/>
      <alias name='video0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x0'/>
    </video>
    <memballoon model='virtio'>
      <alias name='balloon0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x0'/>
    </memballoon>
  </devices>
  <seclabel type='dynamic' model='selinux'>
    <label>system_u:system_r:svirt_t:s0:c211,c271</label>
    <imagelabel>system_u:object_r:svirt_image_t:s0:c211,c271</imagelabel>
  </seclabel>
</domain>
```

Comment: run 'virsh dumpxml guestvmname > guestvmname.xml' and update your question w/ the contents.

Comment: Thanks for posting the log -- nothing here stands out, to me at least.  Next I'd take a look at /var/log/libvirt/qemu/guestvnname.log and look for any helpful info there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not the best solution ever, but I did fix the problem. 
I added:
virsh resume MailServer &> /var/log/MailServer.log 
to /etc/rc.d/rc.local

Might not be the most elegant way to force a start..but it works :).

Thanks for the help.

Comment: That's actually perfectly clever -- glad you figured out a workaround!

Comment: Out of curiosity, is this the only guest on this host?  Have you tried to fire up another guest and see if the same thing happens?

Answer (score 0):

if you know name of your domain you can do this

```
virsh autostart Domain
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but no dice.

Comment: virt-manager has also a checkbox for this...